# I am trying to display two date pickers and disable the 2nd datepicker dates based on first selected date datepicker>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```js
$(function(){
selected = function(){
var selected = new Date($("#start").datepicker('getDate'));
var b = selected.getFullYear();
console.log(b);
if (b <=2000)
{
$("#error").show().addClass("blue");
//$("#error")
}else
{
$("#error").hide();
}
}
});
$(function(){
$("#start").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear : true,
dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
yearRange  : "1995:2020",
onSelect: function(selected){
$("#end").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
}
});
$("#end").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear : true,
dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
yearRange  : "1995:2020",
onSelect: function(selected){
$("#start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
}
});
});
</script>
Start :<input id = "start" type = "text" >
END   :<input id = "end"   type = "text">
<p id = "error" style = "display :none">select after 1990 only</p>
</body>
<style>
.blue 
{
color: blue;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to display two date pickers and disable the 2nd date picker dates based on first selected date picker and I want to show error "select year only after 2000" when we select 1990 year? can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check here

```js
$(function(){
$("#start").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear : true,
dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
yearRange  : "1995:2020",
onSelect: function(selected){

var selected = new Date($("#start").datepicker('getDate'));
var b = selected.getFullYear();
console.log(b);
if (b <=2000)
{
$("#error").show().addClass("blue");
//$("#error")
}else
{
$("#error").hide();
}



}
});
$("#end").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear : true,
dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
yearRange  : "1995:2020",
onSelect: function(selected){
$("#start").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
}
});
});
```

```css
.blue 
{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Start :<input id = "start" type = "text" >
END   :<input id = "end"   type = "text">
<p id = "error" style = "display :none">select after 1990 only</p>
```

Comment: your code is working but I want to display error msg when we selected before 2000 year

Answer (score 0):

Try now

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    checkout.setValue(newDate);
  }
  checkin.hide();
  $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```